# Sorting Linq Result by Year and Month

Tags: linq, sorting, linqpad

I'm using Linqpad to dump (display) a list of counts by year / month.  Everything seems fine but for the life of me I can't get the sort order to display properly.

```
var h = from x in myTable 
where x.Date >= DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013") && x.myField.EndsWith("abc")
group x by new 
{
x.Date.Value.Year,
x.Date.Value.Month
} 
into g

select new 
{  
Year = g.Select(y=>y.Date.Value.Year).First(),
Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Select(n=>n.Date.Value.Month).First()),
Number = g.Count()
};

H.Dump().OrderByDescending(y=>y.Year).ThenBy(m=>DateTime.Parse(m.Month));

2014    January    843
2014    February   635
2014    March      957
2014    April       61
2013    May      1
2013    June      1257
2013    July      1243
2013    August     796
2013    September  341
2013    October    765
2013    November   609
2013    December   630
```

I'm trying to get the output to display

```
2014    April       61
2014    March      957
2014    February   635
2014    January    843
2013    December   630
2013    November   609
```

...

I've also tried

```
H.Dump().OrderByDescending(y=>y.Year).ThenByDescending(m=>DateTime.Parse(m.Month));
```

But that doesn't seem to impact the month sort order at all for some reason.  Any ideas on what I'm doing / understanding wrong?  Thanks!

---

I tried to remove some complexity and changed my month projection to get the Month value.

```
Month = (g.Select(n=>n.Date.Value.Month).First())
```

and updated the dump

```
H.Dump().OrderBy(y=>y.Year).ThenByDescending(m=>m.Month);
```

And my return is the same

```
2014    1   843
2014    2   635
2014    3   957
2014    4   73
2013    5   1
2013    6   1257
2013    7   1243
2013    8   796
2013    9   341
2013    10  765
2013    11  609
2013    12  630
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to sort by the grouping keys:

```
var h = from x in myTable 
where x.Date >= DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013") && x.myField.EndsWith("abc")
group x by new 
{
    x.Date.Value.Year,
    x.Date.Value.Month
} 
into g
orderby g.Key.Year descending, g.Key.Month descending
...
```

Also, you can use `Year = g.Key.Year` etc. in the `select`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, with `DateTime.Parse` based on the month, you've got a new `DateTime`, not a `month`.
And as you don't give a year, the current year will be taken.

So for example, for March 2013 (or 2012), you'll get a DateTime corresponding to March 2014.
And March 2014 will also give you March 2014.

So try to get the month Property of your Datetime !

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year)
.ThenByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Month).Month);
```

By the way I would use

```
DateTime.ParseExact(x.Month, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

Comment: Thanks but for whatever reason I still get the exact same dump and sort order from linqpad. Just for trial / error sake I changed the Month projection to just get the value but I still get the same sort order  2014 1 843
 2014 2 635
 2014 3 957

Comment: Hmmm, one strange thing, you've got one time `h`, and one time `H`, just a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked!  Thanks.

```
var H = from x in myTable
where x.Date >= DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013") && x.myField.EndsWith("abc")      
group x by new 
{
x.Date.Value.Year,
x.Date.Value.Month
} 
into g
orderby g.Key.Year descending, g.Key.Month descending
select new 
{
Year = g.Key.Year,
Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key.Month),
Number = g.Count()
};

H.Dump();
```